# add to iCal and google-calendar buttons to a page

Tags: html, google-calendar-api, icalendar

There are some webpages that have a `add to iCal` and `add to Google Calendar` buttons that when you click, it somehow adds an event to your calendar, would it be iCal or google Calendar.

I need to do that in a webpage, but can't seem to find the documentation about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally it's a simple button with a `ics` file of the event. You can construct your own `ics` file following the [iCalendar protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) or use an existing library, for example, in the .NET programming language, the **[DDay.iCal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/)** is a marvelous tool.

If you want just to manually generate a button with the **Google Calendar button**, Google has it's own generator for it:

> http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide.html

Comment: However, I believe there is no way to pass Google Calendar an iCal file. That would be really useful, as the event data would be kept in sync with the iCal feed.

Comment: sure you can... just import an `.ics` file :) problem is that, it will only use this new calendar as Read-Only Calendar, and that sucks so we can't have both ways, it will only sync from the `ics` source.

Comment: this URL is really helpful, however, I couldn't find any detailed documentation for this with the full list of parameters and options. do you know about something like that?

Comment: the full list is in the [protocol  page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) you can't have more than that, and DDay.iCal gives you access to everything, plus, you can append all custom parameters as well. DDay.iCal has examples where you can look and try yourself.

Comment: Like @ubik said, there's no way to pass Google Calendar an iCal file `ON THE ANDROID APP`. You can do it via the web application, but on mobile it doesn't seem possible

Answer (score 2):

If you'd prefer to take the lazy route and use a pre-built solution, AddThisEvent may suit.
http://addthisevent.com/